# How to get reference to the dispatch method from a component method in my react-native redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In my react-native app, I'm trying to wire up a login button using redux connect.  When I try to trigger my handleLogin function, it looks like `this` in the handleLogin function is bound to the button, and not the component.  What's the best way to structure this method.  I could pass in the dispatch function as an argument to `handleLogin` but is there a cleaner way to get the dispatch reference from within the function?

```
class Profile extends Component {

  handleLogin() {
    // wrong `this`, this.props is null and this refers to the button, not the component
    this.props.dispatch(login);
  }

  handleLogout() {
    this.props.dispatch(logout);
  }

  render() {
    const { dispatch, isAuthenticated, errorMessage, username } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.outer}>
        { isAuthenticated ? (
          <Button style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} textStyle={{ fontSize: 18 }} onPress={() => dispatch(logout)} >
            Logout {username}
          </Button>
        ) : (
          <Button style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }} textStyle={{ fontSize: 18 }} onPress={this.handleLogin(dispatch)} >
            Login
          </Button>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }

};
```

I'm assuming that my connect method automatically wires up dispatch to my components props.

```
Profile.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  username: PropTypes.string,
  photo: PropTypes.string,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  errorMessage: PropTypes.string,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { user } = state;
  const { isAuthenticated, errorMessage, photo, username } = user;
  return {
    username,
    photo,
    isAuthenticated,
    errorMessage,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Profile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You have options when trying to correctly bind a method to an inline callback:

*Also: You're assumption that omitting the* `mapDispatchToProps` *results in the* `dispatch` *being mapped to the props as* `this.props.dispatch` *is correct*.

---

**Use the arrow function**:

```
onPress={this.handleLogin(dispatch)}
```

to:

```
onPress={() => this.handleLogin}
```

// `this` is lexcially bound inside an arrow function, yay!

---

**Use `bind` in the constructor function**:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)

  this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
}
```

---

**Use `bind` within the inline callback**:

```
onPress={this.handleLogin.bind(this);}
```

---

Comment: trying with the arrow function - and it says handleLogin is not defined, do I have to say `onPress={() => this.handleLogin} `?

Comment: Are you binding `handleLogin` within the constructor of Profile class?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey, yes, you need this.  (Just realised I omitted that, corrected it now)

Comment: @Uzzar: yes, binding it within the component constructor where I want to reference it in an inline event.